# PLSQL / DataGrip: create quick documentation

Tags: plsql, datagrip

In earlier days I used a certain comment style for PHP and my IDE would understand that this was quick documentation for the package/method. Now, I use PLSQL and I see that my DataGrip generates such documentation automatically for tables.  I wonder if I can make it so that DataGrip displays some comments as quick documentation as well. If I have this package:

```
create or replace package some_pack
/**  
 *  This method has a certain use
 *  @foo INT expects 0 = Testmode or 1 = Live 
 *  @bar VARCHAR2 team notice, leave null to skip the e-mail
 */
function some_method( foo in INT, bar in varchar2 DEFAULT null) return Int;


declare
  l_ret int;
begin
  /* 
   *  If I forgot how to use some_method 
   *  I could hover the method here and get my comment from the package displayed.
   */
  l_ret := some_pack.some_method(0,null);
end;
```

Comment: Feel free to create feature request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE

Comment: Do you mean "code comments" https://www.dba-oracle.com/t_easyoracle_pl_sql_code_comments.htm ?

Comment: No - I am looking for a way to view certain comments when I use the function in some other spot. I did edit the question, but maybe this feature does simply not exist yet.